# Measure on $\mathbb{R}$ of certain property

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A standard result from real analysis says that for any Lebesgue measurable set $A$, one has the decomposition $A = B \cup E$ where $B$ is a Borel set and $E$ is a null set (we call it property $*$). I'm wondering if there exists a measure $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{A},\mu)$ such that $\mathcal{A}$ contains the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ and $*$ does not hold. I'm trying to construct measures of the form $\mu(A) = m(f^{-1}(A \cap C))$ where $C$ is the ternary Cantor set and $f$ is some increasing continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$. However, I'm not sure whether that's a valid construction that will lead to the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the counting measure on the whole power set $P(\mathbb{R})$, i.e $\mu(A)=|A|$ if $A$ is finite, and $\mu(A)=\infty$ otherwise. Then if $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is any non Borel set then you clearly can't write it as a union of a Borel set and a null set. (as the only null set in this measure space is $\emptyset$)